# Tag filter for favourite questions

Tags: feature-request

Wouldn't be useful if we have a filter for favourite questions by tag?

For example, I would like to search for all my favourite questions with tag [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) or a combination of tags, for example [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf)+[jsf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf2).

[image: My recent Favourite questions]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using

https://stackoverflow.com/search

with `infavorites:userID` option. If you want to search in your favourites you can use `infavorites:mine`. So try maybe queries like

```
infavorites:mine [generics]
```

if you want intersection of tags use

```
infavorites:mine [jsf][jsf2]
```

if you want union you can use `or` in query like

```
infavorites:mine [jsf] or [jsf2]
```

You can find more info about searching options here https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Thanks, mate. That's something I didn't know before. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not an implementation but a query to achieve the desired results.

Just enter parameters for UserId and 2 tags:

### [Tag filter for favourite questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209350/tag-filter-for-favourite-questions)

**[Sample with your Id and jsf + jsf-2 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209350/tag-filter-for-favourite-questions?tag0=jsf&tag1=jsf-2&UserId=1003142)**

Just add a space to the tag1 parameter if you only want to search a single tag.

Comment: That's really cool. Thank you. I'd rather like to have it as a functionality on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Yeah it would be better as functionality in the site, but it will take them a while to implement it if they even choose to implement it. This is just a little work around to help in the meantime.

Answer (score -3):

I use bookmark in my browser like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3
```

Comment: OP is not asking about filtering all questions by tags, by only favourite ones.